# Typedef is declared in other header, is included in necessary files, however produced: Error[Pe020]: identifier "" is undefined. Why?

Tags: c, header-files, iar

Let's say I have the project in C in IAR, and I'm working with these 4 files. I have a header for defines, and another header for extern functions. I also have two .c files, one for main, and one for functions, as shown below.

First header file: header1.h

```
#ifndef __HEADER1_H
#define __HEADER1_H

#include "header2.h"
#include "otherheader.h"

// bunch of 'define' here
typedef uint8_t   macAddr[8];
#endif
```

Another header file: header2.h

```
#ifndef __HEADER2_H
#define __HEADER2_H

//other extern functions here
extern void getMAC(macAddr deviceAddr);
#endif
```

main.c file here:

```
#include "header1.h"
void main ()
{
    macAddr dev1Address = {0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00};
    getMAC(dev1Address);
}
```

function.c file here:

```
#include "header1.h"
void getMAC(macAddr deviceAddr)
{ 
  uint8_t transmit[8];
  for (int i = 0; i<8; i++)
      transmit[i] = deviceAddr[i];
}
```

The error reported is this:

```
Error[Pe020]: identifier "macAddr" is undefined
```

I'm having a little trouble understanding why this does not work. The first header (where `macAddr` is defined) includes the second header (where `getMac()` function is declared), and the first header is included in main.c as well as function.c. As far as I understand, there is no circular includes (as other questions suggested... correct me if I'm wrong, and show me how)

Comment: C does not support classes. Sure this is not C++?

Comment: Order of includes matter. As you say, first header includes the second, but second headers needs the definitions of the first.

Comment: Maybe I'm using the wrong word. It's not class, it's just another c file. I'm more of a C++ programmer, but this is written in C as far as I understand.

Comment: Your `macAddr` typedef is in header1.h, but *after* you `#include "header2.h"`.  So when header2.h is processed, the typedef hasn't been reached yet, and the reference to `macAddr` in the `getMAC()` prototype triggers an error (correctly).

Comment: `#define __HEADER1_H` BTW: preprocessor identifiers with a leading undersccore are reserved. Don't use them.

Comment: @Mat and @Dmitri -- to avoid circular includes, does this mean that I need to `#include header1.h` in header2.h? Would that create circular includes issue?

Comment: @Smiley What you should try to do is place the typedef either early in header2.h (before the `getMAC()` prototype or any other use of it), or into another file that is `#include`d by header2.h and possibly other files that need the typedef but otherwise nothing from header2.h.  From what you've shown I can't see a reason why they're not in the same file.

Comment: the `for()` statement is written `for( initializer; condition; step )`   Notice that each part of the `for()` statement is separated from the other parts via semicolons, not commas.

Comment: note that symbols starting with double underscore, or underscore and a capital letter, are unconditionally reserved for the implementation. Yes, system headers use names with double underscores — they're part of the implementation and aren't allowed to pollute your namespace. You shouldn't pollute their namespace. For all practical purposes, and multiple counter-examples notwithstanding, treat names starting with underscore as reserved for the implementation.

Comment: the posted code 1) is referencing a 5th file: `#include "otherheader.h"` that is not posted.  2) does nothing with the  `transmit[]` array after setting it.  this causes the compiler to raise a warning.  `warning: variable 'transmit' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]`

Comment: under most scenarios, the signature for the main function: `void main()` will cause the compiler to raise a warning about the return type not being `int`.  Suggest changing the signature to: `int main( void )`

Comment: in the file `header1.h` need to insert the statement: `#include <stdint.h>` so the `uint8_t` will be defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that `header1.h` includes `header2.h`, but `header2.h` requires `macAddr` which is not yet defined.

---

Rule of thumb is that each file should include only the files it needs. Thus:

- `header1.h` has a single `typedef`. It should only include `stdint.h`.
- `header2.h` needs `macAddr` to work, thus it should include `header1.h`.
- `main.c` uses getMAC, so it should include `header2.h`. `header1.h` is already included, so no need to include it.
- `function.c` strictly only needs `header1.h`, but it's good practice to make sure that function declaration and definition match, so it should include `header2.h` instead.

It seems like `header1.h` is used as a monolith header that is used to include everything (It's hard to be sure because your example has so few files). This is a *very bad* practice. It can increase compilation times, and makes refactoring hard since dependencies are difficult to track.

Ideally each header should only have single well defined responsibility. It's not always possible, but it's a good goal.

Circular includes are not a huge issue as long as you use header guards as you have, and not include everything everywhere unless it's needed. Sometimes you might need to add extra forward declarations, but that's about it.

---

Here's some additional notes:

- As user3629249 and others noted, you really shouldn't declare symbols starting with `_` underscore. These are reserved for C standard or compiler use.
- I don't recommend using `typedef` on arrays (or pointers). Arrays decay to pointer in some cases without telling you, so when using `typedef` this is hidden from user and can cause bugs with careless use. I would wrap it struct instead:
  `typedef struct { uint8_t address[8]; } MAC_T;`

Comment: assuming that I can't change around the functions and declaration, is there any way that I can make this work? I tried using circular includes, but not working as I hoped to be. And about forward declaration, I tried that and didn't work. I may have declared it wrong. Not sure. For now, I moved the function so it works, but let's just assume that I'm not able to move around the function for some odd reason, how would I go about that?

Comment: @Smiley Your real code is probably more complicated than this, but my first list of how to change includes is what you should consider. If nothing else, move `macAddr` definition to another header (with approriate header guards) and incluce that to other headers. I am not entirely sure how to forward declare array typedefs because I don't use them, so can't help you with that.

Comment: just to keep you updated. I came to learn that `header1.h` is public, and `header2.h` is private. So I made some changes so that `header2.h` is only for `main.c` and `function.c` and not for anywhere else, `but header1.h` can be used anywhere else. 

that being said, both `main.c` and `function.c` has `#include "header2.h"`, and `header2.h` has `#include "header1.h"`. 

You're right, it is more complicated than this as there are many units working together. But your answer is really the answer, it made more sense when we state the purpose for each file.

Comment: @Smiley Yes, header includes an be complex sometimes. If this helped, you can mark the answer, so that others know this question is solved.